# Textbox showing as null WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 3 textboxes that a user can modify to change the RGB colors of certain colors of the window. What I'm doing to give them a visualization is have a box next to said textboxes that shows the color they're making with said RGB values in the textboxes. To do this, I set the TextChanged event for all 3 textboxes to a method that takes the text from the 3 textboxes, converts them to an integer with TryParse, assigns the numbers to a brush, then assigns the brush to the box so the user can see it. The XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBox Name="ColorPickerDisplayRed" Background="Transparent"
         BorderBrush="Transparent"
         FontFamily="Moon 2.0"
         Foreground="#6BAAFF"
         Text="255"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         Margin="0, -1.2, 0, 0"
         TextChanged="UpdateColorPickerDisplay"/>
```

I copied and pasted this for green and blue so everything is the  same except for the name of the textbox. Then, to get the integer values, I have this:

```
private void UpdateColorPickerDisplay(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int R;
        int G;
        int B;

        if (int.TryParse(ColorPickerDisplayRed.Text, out R)) ;
        if (int.TryParse(ColorPickerDisplayGreen.Text, out G)) ;
        if (int.TryParse(ColorPickerDisplayBlue.Text, out B)) ;

        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)R, (byte)G, (byte)B));
        ColorPickerDisplay.Background = brush;
    }
```

But when I run it, I get an error that says "ColorPickerDisplayGreen was null.". Then I tried just setting the text for each box as a test and got the same error. I tried it for all 3 textboxes and it only worked for red. Is it because I'm calling the same method from all 3 text boxes?

Solved, didn't know TextChanged was called immediately.

Comment: It's likely a side-effect of the `TextChanged` event. It is fired before the other textboxes are instantiated. If you want to manage your textboxes with events, have care to place a flag at the beginning of the event handler, so that all the undesired events (fired too early) will not handled. Once the form is completely loaded, clear the flag, and force the textboxes initialization.

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint on it so you can see when the event is called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ? before accessing Text property & it will fix the issue

```
            int R;
            int G;
            int B;

            if (int.TryParse(ColorPickerDisplayRed?.Text, out R)) ;
            if (int.TryParse(ColorPickerDisplayGreen1?.Text, out G)) ;
            if (int.TryParse(ColorPickerDisplayBlue?.Text, out B)) ;

            var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)R, (byte)G, (byte)B));
            ColorPickerDisplayRed.Background = brush;
```